# how to sort persistentSet of grails objects?

Tags: sorting, grails, domain-model, persistent-set

I have two domain models:

```
class Resource{
   String name

   static mapping = {
                 sort name:"asc"
          }
}

class ResourceGroup{
   String groupName

   static hasMany = [resources: Resource]
}
```

controller:

```
def resGroups = ResourceGroup.findAll()
render (
        view: "index",
        model: [resourcegroups: resGroups]
)
```

so and now in my gsp:

```
<g:each in="${resourcegroups}" var="item" status="i">
   ...
   <g:each in="${item.resources}" var="res" status="y">
       <!-- THESE ITEM.RESOURCES ARE UNSORTED! -->
   </g:each>
   ...
</g:each>
```

my Question is how can I sort this "item.resources"? this is a persistent set of hibernate! I thought this could be handled with the mapping sort name: 'asc', but it doesn't work :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a default sort on a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship.  See [documentation here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.5.3%20Default%20Sort%20Order), paying particular attention to the note at the bottom that says:

> These mappings will not work for default unidirectional one-to-many or many-to-many relationships because they involve a join table. See [this issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-4089) for more details. Consider using a SortedSet or queries with sort parameters to fetch the data you need.

The default sort you have specified actually does sort a list of `Resource` objects (i.e. if you got the list like this `Resource.getAll()` the list would be sort in the order you specified).

To do what you want consider creating a tab lib as Don suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028301/groovy-on-grails-sorting-list-output-without-having-to-have-a-sortedset-or-com).

Answer (score 1):

try `item.resources.sort { it.name }` for `"asc"`,

or `item.resources.sort { it.name }.reverse()` for `"desc"`.