# Grails: Changing datasets from the view

Tags: grails

I have a data-driven page that's pulling information from a database. As it stands, the page sorts the data by a field called "type" in the database. But I also want the ability for the user to sort by "date" without needing to reload the page.

Both datasets work fine on their own, I just don't know how to switch between them with just a hyperlink.

I would be fine using a variable in the address bar (ex: http://example.com?sort=year), but it wouldn't be preferential.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you already have both `types` and `years` available in the view, why do you need to call a service again? Look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028301/grails-sorting-list-output-without-having-to-have-a-sortedset-or-comparable-mo), I hope you get would get here what you need. In addition, you can also use JS (Jquery) to sort.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using an html table, the way I do it without reloading (i.e. calling the controller again with a sort parameter) is to use Javascript, particularly jQuery, to do the sorting.  I've had good luck with both [jQuery Datatables](http://www.datatables.net) and [jQuery Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/).  They are jQuery plugins and simple to use.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, it's a publications list with a ton of weird formatting rules, so we can't use a table. I will take a look at those resrouces, but is there any way to do this without using JS/jQuery/PHP? We are trying to keep everything on the Grails/Groovy side.

Comment: "without needing to reload the page". Only JavaScript can do that.

Comment: You can just reload that table, but you will still need JS for an ajax call to do so.

Comment: @James Kleeh is correct - if you can't use Javascript you will have to make a call back to a controller.